# Can I pass a column string to a filter function of dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to parameterize the filter function of dplyr. For e.g 
Instead of

```
mtcars %>% filter(mpg <20)
```

I would like a function where I can pass the column index so that I can do

```
a <- c(4,6)
df <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl %in% a) #- This works
```

But

```
df <- mtcars %>% filter_("cyl %in% a") #Gives 'a' not found
```

and

```
  df <- mtcars %>% filter_("cyl %in% 'a'") # gives 0 rows
```

I will be using a variable where I am using "cyl".
What am I missing?

Comment: Could you let me know which question it is a duplicate of?

Comment: The duplicates are listed above your question.

Comment: As of now I have abandoned the filter method of dplyr and subset the data frame and loop through the values in the vector 'a'. It is slow, but it works. If it can be done with dplyr and filter that would help

Comment: FWIW with the new rlang NSE backend in the devel version, you could do `mtcars %>% filter(eval_tidy(parse_expr(names(mtcars)[1])) > 20)` (whose `eval(parse(...))` echo makes me nervous) or simply `mtcars %>% filter(get(names(mtcars)[1]) > 20)`, though I'm not sure that's robust or recommended. A better option might be the new pronoun structure: `mtcars %>% filter(.data[[names(mtcars)[1]]] > 20)`

Comment: You could do something like this: `mtcars %>% filter_(lazyeval::interp(~col %in% a, col=as.name("cyl")))`

Comment: MrFlick- Your solution works great! Sorrry for the delay.Please answers and I wil accept. Thanks Ganesh